# Desserializar Json API Rest C#

Tags: c#, json, api

Tengo actualmente un API Rest funcionando en el siguiente enlace: http://blasitosoft.somee.com/TraerPersonas

El API Rest retorna este JSON:

```
[{"ID":1,"Nombre":"Bladimir Silva Toro","Telefono":"2114565"},{"ID":2,"Nombre":"Jose Fredy","Telefono":"1111"}] Este JSON es Valido
```

Cuando consumo este API Rest en mi aplicación de escritorio usando la librería Newtonsoft, el valor que se lee no es un JSON valido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que uso en el lenguaje C# es el siguiente:

```csharp
public static DataTable Func_TaerTodasPersonas()
        {
            DataTable DTPersonas = new DataTable();
            HttpWebRequest solicitud = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://blasitosoft.somee.com/TraerPersonas");
            solicitud.Method = "GET";
            solicitud.Accept = "application/json";
            solicitud.ContentType = "application/json";
            solicitud.Timeout = 2000;
            HttpWebResponse respuesta = (HttpWebResponse)solicitud.GetResponse();
            if (respuesta.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                StreamReader lector = new StreamReader(respuesta.GetResponseStream());
                string json = lector.ReadToEnd();
                DTPersonas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
            }
            return DTPersonas;
        }
```

¿Existe alguna forma de leer ese JSON de forma valida? o sea quitar las comillas dobles al comienzo y final además de quitar el carácter \ y que este quede tal cual como se ve en el API Rest.

Agradezco de antemano su colaboración.

Comment: Translate your question to receive an answer, remember that you are in SO in Spanish.

Comment: Hola  Bladimir, bienvenido, esto es SOes, el idioma soportado es el español, te sugiero que traduzcas tu pregunta o la traslades a SO, así evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Comment: listo ya esta en español muchas gracias

Comment: No creo que se puede pasar una array cualquiera y convertirlo en un DataTable....La verdad es que tu código es muy antiguo. DataTable no se ocupa, HttpWebRequest  tampoco se ocupa, Newtonsoft tampoco se ocupa actualmente...que versión de .net estas usando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para leer un JSON usando `WebRequest` debes usar `JsonTextReader`

```
public static DataTable Func_TaerTodasPersonas()
{
    DataTable DTPersonas = new DataTable();
    HttpWebRequest solicitud = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://blasitosoft.somee.com/TraerPersonas");
    solicitud.Method = "GET";
    solicitud.Accept = "application/json";
    solicitud.ContentType = "application/json";
    solicitud.Timeout = 2000;
    HttpWebResponse respuesta = (HttpWebResponse)solicitud.GetResponse();
    if (respuesta.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        StreamReader lector = new StreamReader(respuesta.GetResponseStream());
        JsonTextReader json = new JsonTextReader(lector); // <- ESTO!!
        DTPersonas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json.ReadAsString()); // <- aquí pasamos el string desde el JsonTextReader
    }
    return DTPersonas;
}
```

Como te decía en los comentarios

- Datatable
- Newtonsoft.Json
- WebRequest

Son tecnologías viejas, hoy lo correcto (a mi parecer sería algo así)

```
public static async Task<Persona[]> Func_TaerTodasPersonas()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    return await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Persona[]>("http://blasitosoft.somee.com/TraerPersonas")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es obtener el string que mencionas, luego debes De-Serializarlo hacia un objeto estructurado (Clase) que contenga la estructura que esperas recibir.
Esto se hace con la instruccion:

```
public class Persona
{
 public string ID { get; set; }
 public string Nombre { get; set; }
 public int Telefono { get; set; }
}

DTPersonas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Persona>(string))
```

De esa manera JsonConvert formateara el texto recibido al formato (conocido previamente), si lo conviertes en formato DataTable tendras datos en un formato  creado automaticamente sin estructura y dificil de leer.

Si lo que esperas recibir es una lista de personas en vez de solo un registro pues lo conviertes en una lista de objetos predefinidos.

```
DTPersonas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Persona>>(string))
```